# Parsing CSV from HttpResponseMessage using CSVHelper

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, csvhelper, httpresponsemessage

Currently I am using a two step approach to fetch data from the Web Api and 
deserialize the CSV records into objects.

```
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(queryString);
using (var reader = new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
{
    var csvr = new CsvReader(reader);
    var responseValue = csvr.GetRecords<TrainingDataSetData>().ToList();
    result.Readings.AddRange(responseValue);
}
```

How do I optimize this code?

Comment: What are you trying to optimize here? Time? Memory usage?

Comment: Looks like, the code is reading the response two times. ReadAsStreamAsync and GetRecords.  What I really need is var responseValue = csvr.GetRecords<TrainingDataSetData>().ToList();  Only reason I am using the ReadAsStreamAsync is because CSVReader's  StreamReader ctor arg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to avoid creating an intermediate `MemoryStream` - you could use the `GetStreamAsync` method on `HttpClient`, which should return the raw `NetworkStream` for you pass straight into CsvHelper, instead of `ReadAsStreamAsync`, which will default to reading the full response into a `MemoryStream` before returning.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(queryString)))
{
    var csvr = new CsvReader(reader);
    var responseValue = csvr.GetRecords<TrainingDataSetData>().ToList();
    result.Readings.AddRange(responseValue);
}
```

If you still need access to the `HttpResponseMessage`, you could achieve the same effect by using `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`, which won't buffer the response before returning.

```
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(queryString, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

As to whether or not this is actually more efficient - this is something that would require benchmarking in your particular environment to decide, since it may be conditional on the size of the response, speed of the network etc.